# Did the Tuckersoft director give enough money to the intern?

Tags: black-mirror, black-mirror-bandersnatch

In the first minutes of *Bandersnatch* we can see the director of the "Tuckersoft" company - Mohan Thakur - sending one of his younger employees (I'm assuming an unpaid intern) to get him "20 B&H and a Lion Bar". Then he gives him a note - sadly I can't see the banknote denomination

[image]

If you agree to take his job offer (which is the first game over), you can see a sad looking intern delivering the pack of cigarettes and the candy bar to an extremely happy Mohan... and the camera zooms at suddenly saddened Stefan.

So, did Mohan give enough money for his shopping or was he expecting the intern to pay for his boss? If the latter, did it mean that Stefan noticed, that the boss is greedy and happy to cut the corners for a quick buck?

Edit: I might be wrong, but judging by the colour it might be an old 5 Pounds note (1980-88)

[image]

I don't know the 1984 prices but I kind of doubt that you can buy a pack of smokes and candy bar for that price.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

£5 would absolutely have been enough money in 1984 to buy a pack of 20 cigarettes.

The Office for National Statistics has recorded the average price of 20 cigarettes, going back to 1987, when a pack only cost £1.43. [Here's the link](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/czmp)

The scene was most likely trying to show how Mohan treated and viewed his "lesser" employees, by getting the intern to do menial tasks such as his shopping errands.

Comment: To give a US perspective, in 1990 a pack of cigarettes was 99 cents. Candy bars were 49 cents. From my memory, that is. It stands to reason in 1984 they would have been a little less than that.

Comment: Hmm, ok there goes my theory. But then I don't believe that the intern was abused in any way - it is not uncommon to send intern on such menial tasks like coffee runs

Comment: I don't think he was abused either, but i still think it was probably written in to show the kind of person Mohan is. No one becomes an intern to do errands like that, even if it isn't uncommon